# Making libtool 2.4.6 hangs waiting for lock to be removed

Tags: macos, gnu

I am trying to install gnu libtool 2.4.6 on my Mac. While running make the process hangs with this message:

libtool: link: Waiting for /Volumes/Business/It/software/Unix/packages/gnu/libtool/libtool-2.4.6/libltdl/.libs/dlopen.a.lock to be removed

The same message keeps repeating until I exit terminal. What do I need to do to get around this road block?